# Django querying and listing all objects in a related many to many field

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

Trying to return in the admin page the manytomanyfield's table name in a list function with comma separation.

```
class Machine(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Machine'
        verbose_name_plural = '02 Machines'
    machine_type_choices = (...)
    valuestream = models.ForeignKey(Valuestream, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    machine_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=6,
        help_text="Please exclude the 'm' in the machine number",
        unique=True,
        validators=[
        MinLengthValidator(4, message="Machine numbers have to be greater than 3 digits long"),
        ]
    )
    machine_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=machine_type_choices)
    machine_brand = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    pass

    def __str__(self):
    return str(self.machine_number)




class SWS_Document(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'SWS Document'
        verbose_name_plural = '03 SWS Documents'

    machines = models.ManyToManyField(Machine, related_name='SWS_documents')
    document_description = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="")
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.machines.machine)
```

The last bit of code is what I can't figure out. I'm trying to return all related machines in a list that is associated to SWS_Document.

Comment: `my_sws_document.machines.all()`?

Comment: Suggestion, do not put the meta class before the fields. Check the docs style: [model style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style)

Comment: @gdef_ Thanks I fixed this

Comment: @DanielRosemanThat did not fix it, it would just return my_sws_document is not defined, assuming that was a type I did SWS_Document.machines.all() and got 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

Comment: Yes obviously that was just an example. Since you haven't given any actual code for where you want to call this, I assumed that you had an SWS_Document object already. If you want to show the context where you will be calling this, we can help properly.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry about that, I'm trying to return it in the class SWS_Document model. However, where I'm expecting to see the results of my string is [here](https://i.imgur.com/nNSvkFV.png)

Hoping that I could get it to return each of the machines that it's related to in the model. '123', '456', '765', etc... However, I can't get the query to return any model.

Comment: OK, so you're trying to show it in the admin list_display. I'll put in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't really do this in the model `str` method, as that will override all times when you want the string representation of the model. Do this in an admin method and add the name of that method to the `list_display` attribute.

```
class SWSDocumentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = SWS_Document
    list_display = ('machine_list',)

    def machine_list(self, obj):
        return ', '.join(obj.machines.values_list('machine_number', flat=True))
```

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. However, can you provide an example of your statement 'that will override all the times when you want the string reputation of the model?'

Basically, if I want to get information outside of the model, I should query for it in other areas?

Comment: Well for example if you had an SWS_Document in a template, called say `my_document`, and rendered it just as `{{ my_document }}`; you probably want something more meaningful there than just the list of related machine numbers.